# Temperature correction for specific gravity

Tags: temperature, calculations, specific-gravity

If I want to convert my specific gravity reading from one temperature to an equivalent specific gravity at 60F how do I do it?

Can you give me a correction factor for this case?

Answer (score 5):

All temperatures are in expressed in degrees F.

```
correction = 1.313454 - 0.132674*F + 0.002057793*F*F - 0.000002627634*F*F*F
SG_corrected = SG + (correction * 0.001)
```

- http://www.primetab.com/formulas.html
- agrees with http://brewery.org/library/HydromCorr0992.html

Answer (score 4):

jsled's answer is for when you are using a hydrometer calibrated to 59 degrees F.

The formula to correct a reading for any hydrometer calibration temperature is as follows:

`cg = corrected gravity

mg = measured gravity

tr = temperature at time of reading

tc = calibration temperature of hydrometer`

cg = mg * ((1.00130346 - 0.000134722124 * tr + 0.00000204052596 * tr<sup>2</sup> - 0.00000000232820948 * tr<sup>3</sup>) / (1.00130346 - 0.000134722124 * tc + 0.00000204052596 * tc<sup>2</sup> - 0.00000000232820948 * tc<sup>3</sup>))

Comment: I'm not sure if it's implemented on all of the StackExchange sites, but I believe at least the math ones support TeX or LaTeX markup: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX

Comment: Not sure if its supported, so I added <sup> tags around the exponents in the code block.  Still its a nasty formula to read w/out better formatting.

Comment: This is the correct formula

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a correction table like the one [HERE](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/water-temperature-specific-gravity-d_1179.html).

You just add or subtract the difference from 1.000 at 60 with the temp you are at.

I hate quoting John Palmer, but he also has a table in [Appendix A](http://www.howtobrew.com/appendices/appendixA.html) of Hot to brew.

Comment: Why do you hate quoting John Palmer?

Comment: The link to Palmer's book is now http://howtobrew.com/book/appendices/appendix-a/using-hydrometers